# How to get id value from programmatically created Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mul=0;
            sum=0;

            for(j=0;j<=a-1;j++){

                Log.d("TAG","a ko value inside calc "+a);

                et_grade_grabber=(EditText) findViewById(grade[j]);
                int grade= Integer.parseInt(et_grade_grabber.getText().toString());

                Log.d("TAG","Grade Value of Grade"+j+ " is "+grade);

                et_credit_grabber=(EditText) findViewById(credit[j]);
                int credit=Integer.parseInt(et_credit_grabber.getText().toString());
                Log.d("TAG","Credit Value of Credit "+j+" is "+credit);

                tot_credit= credit+tot_credit;
                Log.d("TAG","Total Credit = "+tot_credit);

                mul=credit*grade;

                sum= sum + mul;
                Log.d("Sum Inside Loop ",""+sum);
            }

            Log.d("TAG","Sum"+sum);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+sum,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sgpa= sum/tot_credit;
            tv_sgpa= new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            tv_sgpa.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv_sgpa.setText("Your SGPA is "+sgpa);
            tv_sgpa.setTextSize(40);


            LinearLayout ll_sgpa = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
            ll_sgpa.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ll_sgpa.addView(tv_sgpa);

            LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_spga);
            linear.addView(ll_sgpa);
        }
    });
}
```

I have successfully create EditText fields using a for(i=0;i<4-1;i++) loop from java file and assign id by setid(Array[i]) inside a loop.

Now again I have retrive the values by method getText().toString() inside a loop for(j=0;j<4-1;j++)

When I input the values in edit text everything works fine except it only retrieves the first value of edit text to all array.

Comment: show code where getting value from `Edittext`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you should use

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfEditTexts.size(); i++){

    //if you need only some of Ids, just check conditions with `if`statement. example:
    if(!((EditText)arrayOfEditTexts.get(i)).getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
         arrayOfEditTexts.get(i).getId(); // and do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: that's right, according to this line `arrayOfEditTexts.size()` and it is in loop, so you will have all ids

Comment: i get my solution thanks anywaz i jus needed to change the assignment of edittext.setid(array[i]) to edittext.setid(i+1000);